# How do I look up the cache_size of a sequence in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.

I created a sequence using the syntax below, but I could not find the cache_size value in the information_schema.sequence table.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQUENCE1
    INCREMENT -1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 3
    START 3
    CACHE 1
    CYCLE;
```

I searched other articles, but there was an answer for PostgreSQL 10 to a question from a user using PostgreSQL 9.2.

That answer is meaningless because the versions are different.
Please tell me how to query in PostgreSQL 9.2.

Comment: Are you aware that Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) . You should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Version 9.2 is EOL since November 2017, almost 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select from the sequence:

```
SELECT min_value, max_value, last_value, increment_by, cache_value, is_cycled 
FROM sequence1 --<< replace with your sequence name
```